# Multiple JOIN view on the same table

Tags: sql

I have this db storing sensors acquisition data,
Acquisitions (acq) come from different Control Units (cu) at fixed intervals (datetime)
Each Acquisition has many different measures stored in Data table

```
acq
    id  
    datetime 
    id_cu     

data          
    id        
    id_acq  
    id_meas
    value
```

I need this kind of view:

```
+---------------------+------+----+-----+
|      datetime       |  v1  | v2 |  v3 |
+---------------------+------+----+-----+
| 2010-09-13 00:05:00 | 40.9 |  1 | 0.3 |
| 2010-09-13 00:10:00 | 41.0 |  2 | 0.3 |
| 2010-09-13 00:15:00 | 41.1 |  4 | 0.3 |
+---------------------+------+----+-----+
```

AS:

- v1 is data.value (for example a humidity)
  WHERE acq.id_cu=1 AND data.id_meas=100
- v2 is data.value (for example a counter)
  WHERE acq.id_cu=2 AND data.id_meas=200
- v3 is data.value (for example a temperature)
  WHERE acq.id_cu=3 AND data.id_meas=300

and so on up to dozens of combinations choosen by user

I ended up with this query but it takes forever on a very small amount of data compared to the one that will be in production

```
SELECT a1.datetime, d1.value, d2.value, d3.value
FROM
    acq a1, data d1
    JOIN acq a2, data d2
        ON a2.id=d2.id_acq AND a2.datetime=a1.datetime
    JOIN acq a3, data d3
        ON a3.id=d3.id_acq AND a3.datetime=a1.datetime
WHERE a1.id=d1.id_acq
    AND a1.id_cu=1 AND d1.id_meas=100
    AND a2.id_cu=2 AND d2.id_meas=200
    AND a3.id_cu=3 AND d3.id_meas=300
```

I guess it would be way faster to get data separately for each `a1.id_centr=x AND d1.id_meas=y` condition and then printing data tabled that way I want with my application.

What is the best (and correct) way to acheive this?

edit: assuming no lacks in acquisitions I mean running this:

```
SELECT datetime, value
FROM acq, data
WHERE acq.id=data.id_acq
    AND (
        id_cu=1 AND id_meas=100
        OR id_cu=2 AND id_meas=200
        OR id_cu=3 AND id_meas=300
    )
ORDER BY id_cu, id_meas
```

the splitting results by id_cu / id_meas change and showing results side by side using a programming language (like python + numpy) is matter of hundreths of seconds vs. ... minutes?

Comment: What is your database, MS MSQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assuming DATETIME and data.id_acq and cu and id_meas all have indexes*, you could try a UNION query with dummy column placeholders and a kludgey MAX(). This ought to work if your data.values are not negative numbers (and if they are you could simply choose an extremely large negative number instead of zero as the dummy placeholder value, a number well outside the possible range):

```
    select FOO.datetime, max(FOO.v1), max(FOO.v2), max(FOO.v3)
    from
     (

     select acq.datetime, data.value as v1,0 as v2, 0 as v3
     from acq inner join data on acq.id = data.id_acq
     where acq.id_cu=1 and data.id_meas=100

     UNION

    select acq.datetime, 0 as v1, data.value as v2, 0 as v3
    from acq inner join data on acq.id = data.id_acq
    where acq.id_cu=2 and data.id_meas=200

    UNION

    select acq.datetime, 0 as v1, 0 v2, data.value as v3
    from acq inner join data on acq.id = data.id_acq
    where acq.id_cu=3 and data.id_meas=300
    ) as FOO
    group by FOO.datetime
```

Comment: Yes it worked and quickly (on my small amount of data)! I tried replacing the dummy 0 with NULL and, at least in SQLite, it does not complain and, at the same time, I have nulls in resulting table in case of missing acquisitions from some control unit. I'll probably vote your solution even if I guess I need to use a trick for a query I don't find so inusual... Of course if someone has a more "orthodox" solution I will evaluate it too! Thank you Tim

Comment: I haven't carefully examined how SQLite manages NULL values in aggregations.  Some databases will exclude rows with NULL in the aggregation and issue a warning. Instead of NULL, you could adopt a conventional value that stands for "data acquisition failure", e.g. negative99999, or whatever makes sense given your possible data ranges, and sideskirt the nulls-with-aggregations issue.

Answer (score 1):

your `JOINS` are a bit confusing (as you are mixing explicit with implicit); try this:

```
SELECT a1.datetime, d1.value, d2.value, d3.value
FROM
    acq a1 
       INNER JOIN data d1 ON a1.id=d1.id_acq
       INNER JOIN acq a2  ON a2.datetime=a1.datetime
       INNER JOIN data d2 ON a2.id=d2.id_acq
       INNER JOIN acq a3  ON a3.datetime=a1.datetime
       INNER JOIN data d3 ON a3.id=d3.id_acq
WHERE 1=1
    AND a1.id_centr=1 AND d1.id_meas=100
    AND a2.id_centr=2 AND d2.id_meas=200
    AND a3.id_centr=3 AND d3.id_meas=300
```

Comment: well, it keeps on taking forever, probably less than before but always unusable, it's running since minutes... rearranging data in application is matter of hundredths of second on the same amount testing of data...

Comment: what database are you using? I seem to recall with SQL Server that the optimizer can't guarantee it chooses the best path above 3 joins (with mysql I've joined 10+ tables and was pleasantly suprised by the results)

Comment: Well honestly I'm testing on Sqlite (while I'd use MySQL in production) but on a rather small amount of data: 80 acquisitions on 10 control units for 18000 values, while this would be just the data collected for less than one day in the production environment